# What thermistor for a TP4056 lithium charge module?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, thermistor

This [TP4056 Li-Ion battery charger datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) specifies an NTC thermistor be used for battery temperature sensing while charging.  Is there any further specification I should know about the NTC thermistor, or is there something I am overlooking in this specification?

Related, are the thermistors typically installed in the battery holder, or attached to the battery?

Comment: Sometimes I have opened up a battery pack, and found one of these thin film resistors. I can imagine that ideally you want that termistor in the middle of the batteries, and if the thermistor don't have direct contact with a battery, account for the temperature delay.

Comment: See this, end of article: https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056-page2.html?utm_content=cmp-true

Comment: Top of page 2 in datasheet tells what V at TEMP pin should be. R1 + R2 + the NTC form a temperature variable voltage that meets the requirements above, or just ground the temp pin. || NTC is usually in contact with the battery.